# Configure Azure Point-To-Site VPN to Virtual Network created in a ResourceGroup

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-network

I am using the new Resource Manager interface to create my Virtual Network.  And I can't figure out how to configure a Point-To-Site VPN and get the VPN client thru the Powershell API.

My Script:

```
$accountName = "a@a.com"
$subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
$vnetname = "VNet1"
$rgname = "MyRG"
$sharedKey = -join(97..122|%{[char]$_}|Get-Random -C 20)

Get-AzureAccount -Name $accountName
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
New-AzureResourceGroup -Name "MyRG" -Location "Central US" -Force

$subnet  = New-AzureVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'GatewaySubnet' -AddressPrefix '10.192.0.0/24'

New-AzureVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location "Central US" -AddressPrefix '10.0.0.0/8' -Subnet $subnet -Force
```

I go into the new Portal and only have DNS options to create, no ability to create a VPN gateway.  I tried scripting it, but couldn't figure out the point to site piece.  Any suggestions?

Gateway script:

```
$gwip = New-AzurePublicIpAddress -Name ($vnetname + "gwip") -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$vnet = Get-AzureVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $rgname
$subnet = Get-AzureVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'GatewaySubnet' -VirtualNetwork $vnet
$gwipconfig = New-AzureVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig -Name ($vnetname + "gwipconfig") -SubnetId $subnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $gwip.Id
$gw = New-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway -Name ($vnetname + "gw1") -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location "Central US" -IpConfigurations $gwipconfig -GatewayType Vpn -VpnType RouteBased
$localGw = New-AzureLocalNetworkGateway -Name ($vnetname + "gw1-local") -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location "Central US" -GatewayIpAddress $gwipconfig -AddressPrefix '172.16.0.0/24'

New-AzureVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name ($vnetname + "gw1-conn") -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location "Central US" -VirtualNetworkGateway1 $gw -LocalNetworkGateway2 $localGw -ConnectionType IPsec -RoutingWeight 10 -SharedKey $sharedKey
```

Comment: It is now possible. You can recheck on what you need to do.

Comment: @activatedgeek do you have any guide for creating a point-to-site virtual network using PowerShell? you said that its now possible, but I had unsuccessful trials trying to run it.

Comment: If you are familiar with the `Azure Resource Templates`, check [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/f16ae43e7d52001942fc70821ce89c16857448cf/101-point-to-site). Simply execute this template with appropriate parameters using PowerShell. (Sorry, can't help you more, not a Windows user.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added 1/19/2016, the Powershell on how to create a Point to Site VPN in a Resource manager Network

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/

Answer (score -1):

There is a  one week old [Document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/) in the MS Azure documentation saying that it is not possible (yet) under the Resource Manager model.

> This article applies to point-to-site connections for virtual networks
>   created using the classic deployment model (Service Management). At
>   this time, point-to-site connections to a virtual network created
>   using the Azure Resource Manager deployment model are not supported.